# How to use Weka JSONLoader in Java IDE?

Tags: java, json, weka

I want to use Weka in order to parse an existing json file in java eclipse. I believe this can be done using the JSONLoader class. After I read the classes' specifications (http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/converters/JSONLoader.html#JSONLoader--) I thought that this could be easily done by doing this:

```
JSONLoader jsonLoader = new JSONLoader(jsonFile);
```

Then I thought by just doing `jsonLoader.getFileDescription()` or `jsonLoader.getSource()` would give me results. This is not how it's done though and I can't find anywhere how to use the JSONLoader class in my java code. So in order not to make this question too broad, how can I create a JSONLoader object that reads a source that is in JSON format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it has nothing to do with eclipse so you should edit your question.

A brief look at the documentation of `JSONLoader`(in the link you provided) can tell that you need to set the data source you want to parse using `setSource` (the constructor is empty):

```
JSONLoader jsonLoader = new JSONLoader();
File f = new File("PATH_TO_YOUR_JSON_FILE");
jsonLoader.setSource(f); //you can also use InputStream instead of a File
```

After doing that you can use other methods that parse your JSON:

```
Instances dataset = jsonLoader.getDataSet();
jsonLoader.getFileDescription();
...
```

Comment: aaaaah thanks a lot man ! This is exactly what I wanted! I can never understand these types of classes' explanation.

Comment: sorry i forgot!

Comment: Do you have any idea about the No 'header' section! error? I get this with all get methods.

Comment: Make sure you JSON file is defined properly. Try to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998871/how-do-i-use-a-json-file-with-weka to better understand how it should be defined